# Move files from source to respective archive location in ssis

Tags: filesystems, etl, ssis-2012, msbi

[image: Move Respective Files to respective archive folder]

I have 2 folders one is Source Folder and another is Archive folder, each folder contains sub folders. Each sub folder contains excel files, so how to move the excel files from source to respective archive folders?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Are you looking for a broad design strategy?

Comment: i am not finding any kind of solutions for this scenario.. please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'File System Task' with operation 'move file' and set values for source and destination file.

Comment: How it will loop each file in each source folders?

Comment: use foreach loop container with file enumerator. below link can be useful for you.

Comment: [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/)